# Fetch value from json object and assign it to a dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using asp.net WebForm page with C#, I have a class `Place` that has the properties `int placeId`, `string place` and `Baladi baladi`.

`Baladi` class has the properties `int baladiId`, `string baladi`.

In *javascript* I am calling a method that returns an object Place. 
And I have a Bootstrap modal with a *TextBox*, *HiddenField* and *DropDownList*,
I am able to set the value of TextBox as `Place.place` and the HiddenField as `Place.placeId`.

What I need is to set the selected index of the DropDownList based on `Place.baladi.baladiId`.
When I try in my code it keeps selecting the first item in the DropDownList.

Below is my code:

```
public class Place
{
    public int placeId { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; }
    public Baladi baladi { get; set; }
}
public class Baladi
{
    public int baladiId { get; set; }
    public string baladi { get; set; }
  }

<script>
        $(document).on("click", ".btnEdit", function () {
            var pid = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "place.aspx/getPlace",
                data: '{placeId: "' + pid + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });

            function OnSuccess(response) {
                console.log(response.d);
                $("#txtEditPlace").val(response.d['place']);
                $("#ddlCity").val(response.d['baladi']['baladiId']);
                $("#hfPlaceId").val((response.d['placeId'] == null ? "" : response.d['placeId']));
            }
            function OnErrorCall(response) { console.log(response); }
        });
    </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int baladiId { get; set; }
```

baladiId is declared as an int.  The val function should only work when passed a string IE `"2"` and `2` are not equivalent values.  Did you try casting the baladidId before setting the dropdown val?

```
$("#ddlCity").val(String(response.d['baladi']['baladiId']))
```

Comment: Can you update with your html then or maybe tell me what `console.log(response.d['baladi']['baladiId'])` outputs.  It is likely that either your are not getting the correct value or your markup does not have an option with the value you received.

Comment: I receive the right value, but still can't assign it.

Comment: Are you sure your `<option value="something">Some Option</option>` actually has the correct value set that is the same as your response?

Comment: it is not the same as the response, it is always setting it to the first item in the list. can you send me a private message please.

Comment: I am sorry but there isn't much I can do besides guess unless you can provide us with an example response and the markup of your dropdown.